# Does there exist a linear operator $A:\Bbb F^5\to\Bbb F^3$ s.t. $\operatorname{Im} A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\Bbb F^3,|x_1|\leqslant 1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

> Does there exist a linear operator $A:\Bbb F^5\to\Bbb F^3$ s.t. $$\operatorname{Im} A=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\Bbb F^3,|x_1|\leqslant 1\right\}\quad?$$
>
> Depending on the answer, give an example or explain why such an operator doesn't exist.

Let $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in\operatorname{Im} A$. Then $|y_1|\leqslant 1$

Checking whether or not $Im$ is closed under scalar multiplication:

Let $\alpha\in\Bbb F$ be arbitrary.

$$\alpha x=(\alpha x_1,\alpha x_2,\alpha x_3)$$
$$\alpha x\in \operatorname{Im} A\implies|\alpha x_1|=|\alpha|\cdot|x_1|\leqslant 1$$
$$x_1\ne 0\implies|\alpha|\leqslant 1$$
so, $\operatorname{Im} A$ is closed under scalar multiplication only for $x_1=0$. The same holds for addition.
$\implies \dim (\operatorname{Im})\le 2\implies\operatorname{Ker} A\geqslant 3$,
$$\operatorname{Im} A=\left\{(0,x_2,x_3)\in\Bbb F^3\right\}$$
We know that $L(\Bbb F^5,\Bbb F^3)\ne\emptyset$ and the trivial $0$-operator definitely satisfies the constraints.
I took canonic bases $e$ for $\Bbb R^5$ and $f$ for $\Bbb R^3$ and thought of writing a composition of projectors $B,C,D$:
$$B:\Bbb R^5\to\Bbb R^4$$
$$C:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^3$$
$$D:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$$
$$A=DCBx$$
So as to get: $yz$-plane $\equiv\; \operatorname{Im} A$.
but it didn't work due to the size of $[A]_e^f\in M_{3\times 5}$

How can I construct, if possible, such a nontrivial operator?

Comment: Here $\mathbb{F} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$, right?

Comment: @G. Chiusole, yes, but our professors don't write that down. We never worked with the field $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed that $\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb F^3: |x_1| \le 1\}$ is not closed under scalar multiplication, and therefore is not a vector space.  Since the image of a linear operator is a vector space, that proves there is no such operator.

Comment: thank you very much! In this case,  finding a proper subset of the given set that might be a vector space is unnecessary?

Comment: She showed that in a special case, when the first coordinate in the image can be non-zero. And there are many non-trivial examples of linear maps which lie outside of this special case. Or am I confusing anything?

Comment: @Mihail One counterexample is enough to show that a given set is not closed under scalar multiplication.  And then that set can't be the image of a linear operator.

Comment: @Robert the question was not if in general this set is closed or not under a scalar multiplication.

Comment: The question was whether this set is the image of a linear operator.  The image of a linear operator is closed under scalar multiplication.  This set is not.  Case closed.

Comment: @Robert my bad. For some reason I was thinking that image was supposed to be a "subset" of the elements with absolute value of the first coordinate less or equal to one rather than a "set". Sorry for the confusion.